# SQL query for returning nearest parent containing a value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the two following tables in SQL. The first table a hierarchy with IDs, Parents and OwnerGroup. The second table is a collection of members in each OwnerGroup. The task is to return the nearest OwnerGroup upwards in the hierarchy that contains actual Members.

The SQL query at the bottom is a simplified version of my query that returns correct Members for IDs 1-4, but for IDs 5 and 6, it returns a empty result since MemberInOwnerGroup don't contain a value for OwnerGroup='C'. In that case the query should continue traversing the Product table and get result in OwnerGroup='B'.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

**Product**

```
------------------------------
| ID | ParentID | OwnerGroup |
------------------------------
| 1  |          |     A      |
| 2  |     1    |            |  
| 3  |     2    |     B      |
| 4  |     3    |            |
| 5  |     4    |     C      |
| 6  |     5    |            |
------------------------------
```

**MemberInOwnerGroup**

```
-----------------------
| OwnerGroup | Member |
-----------------------
|     A      | Alice  |
|     A      | Bob    |
|     B      | Dan    |
|     C      |        |
-----------------------
```

**SQL query for returning Member**

```
WITH Hierarchy(ID, ParentID, OwnerGroup, NearestOwnerGroup)
AS
(
    SELECT ID, ParentID,OwnerGroup,CAST(OwnerGroup AS VARCHAR(MAX))
        FROM Product
        WHERE ParentID IS NULL    
    UNION ALL
    SELECT NextGeneration.ID, NextGeneration.ParentID,NextGeneration.OwnerGroup,
    CAST(CASE WHEN NextGeneration.OwnerGroup not like ''
        THEN(CAST(NextGeneration.OwnerGroup AS VARCHAR(MAX)))
        ELSE(Parent.NearestOwnerGroup)
    END AS VARCHAR(MAX))
        FROM Product AS NextGeneration
        INNER JOIN Hierarchy AS Parent ON NextGeneration.ParentID = Parent.ID    
)
SELECT Member FROM MemberInOwnerGroup WHERE OwnerGroup IN
(
    SELECT Hierarchy.NearestOwnerGroup 
        FROM Hierarchy
        WHERE Hierarchy.ID = '6'
)
```

**The expected result for different IDs should be the following**

```
--------------------
| ID | Member      |
--------------------
|  1 | Alice, Bob  | 
|  2 | Alice, Bob  |
|  3 | Dan         |
|  4 | Dan         |
|  4 | Dan         |
|  6 | Dan         |
--------------------
```

Comment: What version of SQL are you using (MySQL, Oracle, etc.) ?

Comment: You got to `A` and `B`  OwnerGroups, but what about `C`?

Comment: @gofr1: I have edited my post to clarify. MemberInOwnerGroup contains C, but there is no value in the Member column

Answer (score 0):

I have added in a join to the `MemberInOwnerGroup` table that returns the members of the Group (or ParentGroup if blank).  This creates duplicate rows in the `cte` which are handled by the `where exists` in the resulting `select` statement.

Depending on the size of your dataset, this may cause performance issues:

```
with Hierarchy as
(
     select ID
           ,ParentID
           ,OwnerGroup
           ,cast(OwnerGroup as varchar(max)) as NearestOwnerGroup
     from Product
     where ParentID is null

     union all

     select NextGeneration.ID
           ,NextGeneration.ParentID
           ,NextGeneration.OwnerGroup
           ,cast(case when GroupMember.Member = '' then Parent.NearestOwnerGroup else GroupMember.OwnerGroup end as varchar(max)) as NearestOwnerGroup
     from Product as NextGeneration
        inner join Hierarchy as Parent
            on NextGeneration.ParentID = Parent.ID

        inner join (select OwnerGroup
                        ,Member
                    from MemberInOwnerGroup
                    ) GroupMember
            on GroupMember.OwnerGroup = case when NextGeneration.OwnerGroup = '' then Parent.OwnerGroup else NextGeneration.OwnerGroup end
)
select m.Member
from MemberInOwnerGroup m
where exists (select null
                from Hierarchy h
                where h.NearestOwnerGroup = m.OwnerGroup
                    and h.ID = '6'
                )
```